# Linux Grep or Awk to find strings and store into array

Tags: awk, grep, extract

I would like to print the string in the following pattern. And I would like to store it in a array. Please help me, I need O/p as follows

```
test11
orcl
```

My commands/Tries

```
egrep -i ":Y|:N" /etc/oratab | cut -d":" -f1 | grep -v "\#" | grep -v "\*" | tr -d '\n' | sed 's/ /\n/g' | awk '{print $1}'
```

Above commands O/p:

```
test11orcl
```

> Contents of Oratab will be as follows,

```
[oracle@rhel6112 scripts]$ cat/etc/oratab
#
# This file is used by ORACLE utilities.  It is created by root.sh
# and updated by the Database Configuration Assistant when creating
# a database.

# A colon, ':', is used as the field terminator.  A new line terminates
# the entry.  Lines beginning with a pound sign, '#', are comments.
#
# Entries are of the form:
#   $ORACLE_SID:$ORACLE_HOME:<N|Y>:
#
# Multiple entries with the same $ORACLE_SID are not allowed.
#
#  
test11:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1:N 
orcl:/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1:N
```

> End of Cat Output

From the above file am trying to extract the STRING before the `:/`

Answer (score 1):

As a start, try this:

```
$ cat input.txt
test11:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1:N
orcl:/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1:N

$ awk -F: '{print $1}' input.txt
test11
orcl
```

**update**

Using bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

ARRAY=()
while read -r line
do
    [[ "$line" = \#* ]] && continue
    data=$(awk -F: '{print $1}' <<< $line)
    ARRAY+=($data)
done < input.txt

for i in "${ARRAY[@]}"
do
    echo "$i"
done
```

In action:

```
$ ./db.sh 
test11
orcl
```

Comment: Thanks but I could not print the same when I put into shell script. It is printing as follows,

test11 orcl

My shell script:
osid=`egrep -i ":Y|:N" $loc_ora | cut -d":" -f1 | grep -v "\#" | grep -v "\*" | sed -r 's/^([^:]*):.*$/\1/g'

Comment: I don't understand the intention with you shell-script. Doesn't the awk above work for you?

Comment: I tried to use awk as follows,
awk -F: '{print $1}' /etc/oratab

O/p
Whole content of Oratab is printing and then the 2 strings are printed.

Comment: Ah, I see, to ignore lines starting with a `#`, you can use ` awk -F: '/^#/{next}{print $1}' input.txt`

Comment: Okay can I remove the blank spaces ? Why because I need to store each strings into an array, so that I can make a list of STRINGS from that file.

Comment: what shell are you using? bash?

Comment: Yes

[root@rhel6112 ~]# ps -p $$
ps -p $$
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 5317 pts/0    00:00:00 bash

Comment: See update for a bash-solution that puts each string into an array

Answer (score 0):

You could use `sed` also,

```
sed -r 's/^([^:]*):.*$/\1/g' file
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat cc
test11:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1:N
orcl:/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1:N
$ sed -r 's/^([^:]*):.*$/\1/g' cc
test11
orcl
```

OR

```
$ sed -nr 's/^(.*):\/.*$/\1/p' file
test11
orcl
```

Comment: Thanks but when I do the same in script I could not extract the particular string.
osid=`egrep -i ":Y|:N" /etc/oratab | cut -d":" -f1 | grep -v "\#" | grep -v "\*" | sed -r 's/^([^:]*):.*$/\1/g'

So you mean like this
sed -r 's/^([^:]*):.*$/\1/g' /etc/oratab

Since oratab file is having lot of commented lines, so I would like to extract only the string from N no. of lines in that file.

Comment: post the exact contents of `/etc/oratab` file, and ask another question from that.

Comment: post the contents in your question please. @KarthikSinghDBA

Comment: just without `>`, i will edit it. post the exact output of cat command.

Comment: @KarthikSinghDBA see my last edit. It will works according to your input.

Comment: I tried using sed to remove the blank lines and white spaces

sed -e 's/^[\t](.*):\/.*$/\1^$/p/d' /etc/oratab

How do I do it?

Comment: you get the output, why are you trying to remove the blank lines?

Comment: to remove the blank lines `sed '/^$/d' file`

Comment: Oh yes.
sed -nr 's/^(.*):\/.*$/\1/p' /etc/oratab
test11
orcl

But while printing the same via script the output differs
test11 orcl

I would like to store each sting into array and compare it with user entered string.